# Google GKE and Ingress where prefix give error: invalid ingress spec

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup a ingress network for my Google GKE, I have tested locally on Minikube and its working as I expect.

When I hit the domain with the prefix /test-1 or /test-2 its sending me to the root of the my service /.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-test-domain-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - api.test-domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: api.test-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test-1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-1-port-forwarding
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /test-2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-2-port-forwarding
            port:
              number: 8081
```

The issue is when I put it into my Kubernetes cluster on Google (GKE) then I get this error

> Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: failed to validate prefix
> path /test-1(/|$)(.*) due to invalid wildcard; failed to validate
> prefix path /test-2(/|$)(.*) due to invalid wildcard

I have trying in hours to trying to get it to working and what's going on, whiteout any kind of result, so really hope some one here can explain about what I did wrong and what I shut change to resolved my problem.

Comment: What are you trying to match?  just /test-1 and anything under /test-1?  i.e. /test-1/users or /test-1/myendpoint?  I've never seen wildcards like that before: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples

I also usually use ImplementationSpecific as the pathType and let the IngressClass figure it out :D

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when you call the URL api.domain.com/test-1/some-rule then in my API services its route with only /some-rule and its working success on Minikube but have error on GKE

Comment: Ah!  You need to specify the ingress class. (kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx") in your annotations.  It will default to "gce" and so if you're using nginx ingress then you need to specify.  You didn't need to specify for minikube because it's not one GKE :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i just missing a external IP address, its going away after I change to NGINX, did you know something about it?

Comment: I think you should just destroy and recreate the LB piece to be safe.  When it defaults to "gce" ingress class, it's an L7 LB (HTTP), vs an "nginx" ingress class LB which is a TCP/UDP LB, so you should get an external IP.

EDIT: did you deploy the nginx-ingress via Helm (or something?) -- it should Ingress resource there should provision you the aforementioned TCP/UDP load balancer and that's where you'd get your external IP from

Answer (score 2):

GKE Built-in Ingress supports wildcard but with some [conditions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services). From the doc:

```
The only supported wildcard character for the path field of an Ingress is the * character. The * character must follow a forward slash (/) and must be the last character in the pattern. For example, /*, /foo/*, and /foo/bar/* are valid patterns, but *, /foo/bar*, and /foo/*/bar are not.
```

If you want to use NGINX you will have to deploy it, GKE doesn't ship with NGINX out of the box. Keep in mind that this is something you will have to maintain and take care of yourself. It's a valid choice to make if the GKE default ingress doesn't support what you need to do (like headers re-write for example) but just be aware of the fact that it's an extra piece of software.

Comment: Thanks for response, its fine to use GKE for me, its just important everything after /foo/bar* will be sending to my services and not the full path, is this a option?

Comment: That's not valid neither i'm afraid, it has to look like /foo/bar/*. The wildcard has to be always after a forward slash /

Comment: Okay, then I need to use NGINX in this case, or I change the logic/architecture of my way to communicate with GKE services in general, thanks a lot.